# Alternative to UNION operation when getting data from one row into multiple rows?

Tags: sql, union

I am trying to get data from one row in a table into three rows in a temp table, so I can update the data based on values in a different, and I am wondering if there is a better approach than doing a UNION operation.

Here is the basic UNION syntax that gets the data from one row into the three rows I want:

```
    (SELECT 
    0 as lead_id,
    'RV' as lead_type,
    '' as lead_serial,
    rv_amplitude as amplitude,
    rv_pulse_width as pulse_width,
    rv_sensitivity as sensitivity
    FROM program_parameters WHERE event_id = 33636)
    UNION
    (SELECT
    0 as lead_id,
    'LV' as lead_type,
    '' as lead_serial,
    final_amplitude as amplitude,
    final_pulse_width as pulse_width.
    final_sensitivity as sensitivity
    FROM program_parameters WHERE event_id = 33636)
    UNION
    (SELECT
    0 as lead_id,
    'ATRIAL' as lead_type,
    atrial_amplitude as amplitude,
    atrial_pulse_width as pulse_width,
    atrial_sensitivity as sensitivity
    FROM program_parameters WHERE event_id = 33636)
```

so that my final data is a three row table with columns.

The only key value I have to get this data is the event_id, and there is only one row per event_id in the table.

Is there a better way to get this data into separate rows other than a UNION operation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`UNION` is the right solution here.

This is what you need to use when you want to have separate result sets as one set.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution seems to be the Union, however, you can try using a table variable and a cross join

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (lead_type VARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO @t VALUES ('LV')
INSERT INTO @t VALUES ('RV')
INSERT INTO @t VALUES ('ATRIAL')

SELECT 0 as lead_id,
t.lead_type as lead_type,
'' as lead_serial,
CASE t.lead_type 
  WHEN 'LV' THEN rv_amplitude 
  WHEN 'RV' THEN final_amplitude 
  WHEN 'ATRIAL' THEN atrial_amplitude
END as amplitude,
CASE t.lead_type 
  WHEN 'LV' THEN rv_pulse_width
  WHEN 'RV' THEN final_pulse_width
  WHEN 'ATRIAL' THEN atrial_pulse_width
END as pulse_width,
CASE t.lead_type 
  WHEN 'LV' THEN rv_sensitivity
  WHEN 'RV' THEN final_sensitivity
  WHEN 'ATRIAL' THEN atrial_sensitivity
END as sensitivity
FROM program_parameters
CROSS JOIN @t t
WHERE event_id = 33636
```

Comment: How will this help with getting the different columns to show one under the other?

Comment: Well... honestly I don't know... :D ... but I think the union will incur in 3 SELECTS over the same row

Comment: @Oded, the condition(s) on selection from program_parameters are now present once instead of 3 separate places - this would make it slightly easier to maintain than the OP's query.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly a slight improvement:

```
 SELECT 0 as lead_id,
        lead_type,
        '' as lead_serial,
        case lead_type
            when 'RV' then rv_amplitude
            when 'LV' then final_amplitude
            when 'ATRIAL' then atrial_amplitude
        end as amplitude,
        case lead_type
            when 'RV' then rv_pulse_width
            when 'LV' then final_pulse_width
            when 'ATRIAL' then atrial_pulse_width
        end as pulse_width,
        case lead_type
            when 'RV' then rv_sensitivity
            when 'LV' then final_sensitivity
            when 'ATRIAL' then atrial_sensitivity
        end as sensitivity
 FROM (SELECT 'RV' as lead_type union SELECT 'LV' UNION SELECT 'ATRIAL') dummy
 CROSS JOIN program_parameters 
 WHERE event_id = 33636
```

(Very similar to Jhonny's, but using an inline view instead of a temporary table.)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean temp table in the conventional sense... `UNION` operations involve resolving duplicate rows. The use of literals in your table expression means it will have no duplicate rows, therefore you could use three separate `INSERT` statements.

...however, you may mean a derived table, CTE, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up changing this slightly, then joining on a second table to get the serial number and other values, after adding the lead_area (lead_type from my original question became lead_area, due to another column named lead_type) column to the second table.

CREATE PROCEDURE usp_IcdLeadProgramming( 
    @encounterID INT,
    @patientID INT
)
AS
    BEGIN

```
-- Create temp table for final results.
CREATE TABLE #tmp(
    lead_area VARCHAR(10),  
    amplitude FLOAT, 
    pulse_width FLOAT, 
    sensitivity FLOAT)

-- Get the values out of the program_parameters table record
INSERT INTO #tmp
SELECT 
        'RV' as lead_area, 
        rv_amplitude as amplitude, 
        rv_pulse_width as pulse_width, 
        rv_sensitivity as sensitivity 
FROM    program_parameters 
WHERE   event_id = @encounterID 
UNION
SELECT 
        'LV' as lead_area, 
        final_amplitude as amplitude,
        final_pulse_width as pulse_width,
        final_sensitivity as sensitivity
FROM    program_parameters 
WHERE   event_id = @encounterID
UNION
SELECT 
        'ATRIAL' as lead_area, 
        atrial_amplitude as amplitude,
        atrial_pulse_width as pulse_width,
        atrial_sensitivity as sensitivity
FROM    program_parameters 
WHERE   event_id = @encounterID


-- Get the current leads and join to the values.
SELECT 
        l.lead_id,
        l.lead_type,
        l.lead_serial, 
        l.lead_system, 
        l.lead_location,
        ll.lead_area,
        t.amplitude,
        t.pulse_width,
        t.sensitivity
FROM    
        leads l
INNER JOIN 
        lead_location_type ll
ON      l.lead_location = ll.lead_location_code
INNER JOIN #tmp t
ON      ll.lead_area = t.lead_area
WHERE   l.patient_id = @patientID 
AND     lead_removal_date IS NULL 
AND     ll.lead_area IS NOT NULL 

DROP TABLE #tmp

END
```